# Eye of gnome does not autorefresh image

Tags: 15.10, eog

Ever since I upgraded from Ubuntu 13 to 15.10, Eye of GNOME stopped autorefreshing images when they are being overwritten by another program while being opened.

I ***did*** check the "refresh image" plugin in the `Edit -> Preferences` menu.

I am running Eye of GNOME 3.16.3, GNOME Shell 3.16.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's working today with: 3.18.2

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same problem since upgrading to 15.10, and the auto-reload was central to my workflow. The other image viewer Eye of Mate (eom) seems to be a clone of eog, with the same issue. Many other similar bug reports on the net as well.

I ended up using the [geeqie](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/geeqie) image viewer instead, which **does** auto-reload images on filesystem changes.